# Sencha Touch : How to set floating panel size for different device?

Tags: size, sencha-touch, extjs

I am new to Sencha Touch (experienced with ExtJS). In my application, I need to create some floating panels as modal dialogs. Now, I am really confused how to set the size of these floating panels which will be sized properly according to the devices.

Do I need to get the browser height/width and set the size appropriately or do I need to provide some size in percent?

Any help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To dynamically control the width of a Panel you can use the 'width' param within the Panel.

You can force your own value inside this width, but you can also make a function that dynamically sets the width according to the viewport.

For example, a modal panel;

```
    var editPnl = new Ext.Panel({
        floating: true,
        centered: true,
        modal: true,
        draggable: true,
        width: calculateDesiredWidth(),
```

And the function that is called to calculate a decent width;

```
    var calculateDesiredWidth = function() {
        var viewWidth = Ext.Element.getViewportWidth(),
            desiredWidth = Math.min(viewWidth, 400) - 10;

        return desiredWidth;
    };
```

If I misinterpreted your question please say so.

Comment: I tried this out today 12/18/2013 and `Ext.Element.getViewportWidth()` didn't work. I looked in the API and found this though, which worked. `Ext.Viewport.getWindowWidth()`

Answer (score 4):

To do what you request, you can define a function that looks at the user device type and set the "width" and "height" params according to it, alternativelly, you can even do that inline.
I post you an example to show you how change your panel size if you are using a mobile phone or a tablet device:

Inline Example

```
var myPanel = new Ext.Panel({
    floating: true,
    centered: true,
    modal: true,
    draggable: true,
    width: (Ext.is.Phone ? 200 : 600),
    height: (Ext.is.Phone ? 300 : 800)
 });
```

You can even target on different mobile phone types in this way:

```
var myPanel = new Ext.Panel({
    floating: true,
    centered: true,
    modal: true,
    draggable: true,
    width: getPanelSize('width'),
    height: getPanelSize('height')
 });
```

Then define in your code the following function:

```
getPanelSize = function(sizeType){

    switch(sizeType){

       case 'width':

          if(Ext.is.iPhone) return 200;
          if(Ext.is.Blackberry) return 150;
          if(Ext.is.Android) return 180;

          break;

       case 'height':

          if(Ext.is.iPhone) return 300;
          if(Ext.is.Blackberry) return 100;
          if(Ext.is.Android) return 150;

          break;

    }

}
```

Hope this helps.